How to set a background alarm in Android Studio with Kotlin for the built-in Clock app?
I'm trying to create a background alarm in an Android app using Kotlin, specifically to set an alarm in the built-in Clock app. However, I'm running into issues with schedule_exact_alarm and the required permissions.
My goal is to reliably schedule the alarm in the system's Clock app, even if my app is in the background. What is the best approach to achieve this, considering the recent restrictions on alarms and background tasks in Android?
Any guidance, code examples, or best practices would be greatly appreciated.
I expected this to set an alarm that integrates with the system Clock app reliably. However, I encountered issues with permission requests (SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM) not being granted or the alarm not triggering as expected when the app is in the background.


specifically to set an alarm in the built-in Clock app

There is no requirement that there be a built-in Clock app. If there is one, there is no requirement that it support third-party apps scheduling alarms in it. You are welcome to [use AlarmClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock, such as ACTION_SET_ALARM, to try to interact with an alarm clock app, but you need to handle the cases where:

There are no alarm clock apps
There is exactly one alarm clock app
There are two or more alarm clock apps


even if my app is in the background

That does not appear to be a viable option. Interacting with an alarm clock app using AlarmClock involves starting an activity, and you cannot do that from the background in general.
